# Zustand , There seems to be a problem with the 'Zustand persist function'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, zustand

I have created 2 Zustand stores in react application,one is called LoginStoreSlice in login.ts, and the other is called GlobalStoreSlice in global.ts,and I will place these two stores in the index.ts file in the store directory.

BUG is this, The setColor and todoColor functions in GlobalStoreSlice no longer exist,why?
But anything that is not encapsulated by the Persist function middleware can exist normally.
So,Have you encountered this problem? How did you solve it? Please help me...

[layout page code]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/POWuS.png)

[F12 console printing]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLbdF.png)

```js
// global.ts code

import {persist} from "zustand/middleware";

const Storage = {
    name: "primaryColor",
}

export const GlobalStoreSlice = persist(
    (set) => (
        {
            primaryColor: "#247fff",
            setColor: (color) => set(() => ({primaryColor: color})),
            todoColor: () => set(() => ({primaryColor: "black"}))
        }
    ),
    Storage
)

export const createFishSlice = (set) => ({
    fishes: 0,
    addFish: () => set((state) => ({fishes: state.fishes + 1})),
})
export const createBearSlice = (set) => ({
    bears: 0,
    addBear: () => set((state) => ({bears: state.bears + 1})),
    eatFish: () => set((state) => ({fishes: state.fishes - 1})),
})

// login.ts

import {persist} from "zustand/middleware";

const Storage = {
    name: 'userInfo'
}

export const LoginStoreSlice = persist(
    (set) => (
        {
            userInfo: null,
            setUserInfo: (info) => set(() => ({userInfo: info})),
        }
    ),
    Storage
)

// index.ts

import {create} from "zustand";
import {devtools, persist} from "zustand/middleware";
import {LoginStoreSlice} from '@/stores/login'
import {GlobalStoreSlice, createBearSlice, createFishSlice} from '@/stores/global'

export const UseStore = create(
    devtools(
        (...a) => ({
            ...LoginStoreSlice(...a),
            ...GlobalStoreSlice(...a),
            ...createBearSlice(...a),
            ...createFishSlice(...a),
        })
    )
)
```

The main question is why the setColor and todoColor of GlobalStoreSlice are Null in my code ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you not share your code using images and rather as code blocks? Also, make sure that you only share the problematic parts of your code instead of everything.

Comment: Yes,  The code block I provided is only for better reproduction of this issue

Comment: Don't use the slice pattern. Just create 4 small stores, it is also good to keep the store modularity. In this way, the persist middleware won't make any errors. If you want some functions which change states from different stores, just use getState() and setState() to access the states.

Comment: I know, but what I don't understand is why using the slicing mode cannot meet this requirement. Is it a bug in Zustad?

Comment: if you change the order of `LoginStoreSlice` & `GlobalStoreSlice` then `setColor` and `todoColor` functions are available in store. I didn't see any example where each slice is wrapped with persisit. Only store should be wrapped with persist middleware.

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique if this is true, then this needs to be stated somewhere VERY explicitly. I had run into the same issue and was struggling with this for a while. Thanks for the heads up :)